# Want to make the Poster?

Tags: beamerposter, posters, tikzposter

I want to make the poster for Mathematics Games in same writing format

[image]

Comment: Is that a font or an image?  Because using TikZ or PSTricks or anything else to mimic either seems a lot more difficult than loading a font or using an `\includegraphics`...  Another option would be to take your drawings and convert them to a personal font using (non-TeX-related) utilities like [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) and [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/)...

Comment: @joe This is Image

Comment: Well, you can do `\usepackage{graphicx}` and then `\includegraphics[<options>]{<filename>}`.  But as to how that would fit in with the whole document is unclear.  Alternatively, you could use something like the `eso-pic` package to include it as the background of a (part of the) document.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We could use the [`FFF Tusj`](http://www.dafont.com/fff-tusj.font) font from [Dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/). It's 100% free font. After unzipping the file I am renaming the file name to have no spaces there (Otherwise, I would have some difficulties to load the font in LuaLaTeX via [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)).
The other used font is Comfortaa by Johan Aakerlund, available from http://www.dafont.com/comfortaa.font. It's also free font.

If we run `otfinfo -i FFFTusj.ttf`, we are getting information that it's work by Magnus Cederholm from 2008, http://www.formfett.net/. I've used this font to create this poster in [2011](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/konference/index2011.htm) as an invitation to the [TeXperience](http://www.cstug.cz/konference/) conference (I'm sorry I haven't found my old source codes, it's a [simple poster](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/konference/2011/texperience2011_oranzova_stakan.pdf) with some text and graphics in it, no fancies).

My bachelor student, Ondřej Krybus, prepared three colorful versions, we chose the orange one back in 2011 as it was one of the main [university](http://www.utb.cz/) colors.

[image: an example of font in use]

[image: original versions]

---

> **Using the font**

I am enclosing an example and its preview, we can run `xelatex` and `lualatex` after installing the font among system fonts. I'm not sure how to use/load the font in mathematical regimes, so I've used `\char` instead to get several mathematical symbols in the document.

**Update 1:** We could use the [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package for this purpose. Let's write these two lines in the document preamble:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{FFFTusj.ttf} % or =literal
```

I also enclose one close-up and a screenshot of all glyphs in the font using [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/).

```
% run: xelatex or lualatex mal-fff-tusj.tex
% http://www.dafont.com/fff-tusj.font
% I am deleting space in the file name to "FFFTusj.ttf" as I am having a problem to load the font in LuaLaTeX.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{100,126,151}
\definecolor{mgreen}{RGB}{16,58,65}
\definecolor{mgray}{RGB}{10,10,10}
\newfontfamily\fff{FFFTusj.ttf}
\begin{document}
Text before.
{\color{mblue}\fff 2014 [Hello World \char"221E!]}\par
Text in the middle. {\color{mgreen}\fff\char"00BC\char"222B+=\%\char"2211\char"221A}\par
{\color{mgray}\fff Mathematics -90\char"02DA, +45\char"00B2\ \char"00A5} Text after.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

[image: mwe: close-up]

[image: a preview of glyphs in FontForge]

---

> **Update 2: A skeleton of the poster**

I tried my magic to prepare a skeleton of the poster.

I've downloaded [FFF Tusj font](http://www.dafont.com/fff-tusj.font) and [Comfortaa font](http://www.dafont.com/comfortaa.font) from Dafont.com. After unzipping, I've renamed `FFF Tusj.ttf` to `FFFTusj.ttf` to have no difficulties in `lualatex`. After that I installed all four font files among my system fonts.

I enclose the source code of the skeleton and a preview of it. We can run `xelatex` or `lualatex` (tested). We need two runs of TeX as I am using absolute positioning in TikZ.

Please feel free to modify the poster to fit your needs! The `\mylogo` command takes four parameters separated by spaces. The first one is color of `TeX` and year, the second one is color of other parts in logo, the third one is scale and the last one is rotation.

```
% run: xelatex or lualatex mal-texperience.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\fff{FFFTusj.ttf} % [ExternalLocation] % if the font is in working directory only
\newfontfamily\con[
  %ExternalLocation, % if fonts are in working directory
  BoldFont=Comfortaa-Bold.ttf, 
  ItalicFont=Comfortaa-Light.ttf,
  ]{Comfortaa-Regular.ttf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{239,124,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{198,198,198}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\mylogo#1 #2 #3 #4 {%
  \rotatebox{#4}{%
  \scalebox{#3}{%
  {\fff\color{#2}\raisebox{1.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{4th}%
  \kern-1.5ex{\color{#1}\scalebox{4}{T\raisebox{-0.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{E}X}}%
  \kern-6.5ex\raisebox{-1.55ex}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{0.75}{PERIENCE}}%
  {\color{#1}\raisebox{-3.1ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{2011}}}}%
  }% End of \scalebox...
  }% End of \rotatebox...
  }% End of \mylogo...
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[yshift=-7cm] at (current page.north) {\mylogo myorange black 2 0 };
\foreach \x/\y/\s in {2/6/90, 5/7/-90, 8/7/0, 0/3/0, 0/0/-90, 3/-2/90, 6.5/-1.5/0, 10/0/-90, 12/3/0, 12/6/180} {
  \node[xshift=\x cm, yshift=-\y cm] (current page.south west) 
    {\mylogo mygray mygray 1 {\s} };
}% End of \foreach...
\node[minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=0.4\paperheight, fill=myorange, anchor=south] at (current page.south) {};
\node[minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2mm, fill=myorange, anchor=south, yshift=0.4\paperheight+3mm] at (current page.south) {};
\node[align=center, scale=2, font=\bfseries\con, yshift=-4mm] at (current page) {{\color{myorange} From date to date, year}\\
Where, City and State\\
The name of the hotel
};
\node[align=left, xshift=1cm, yshift=1cm, anchor=south west, font=\bfseries\con, scale=1.4] at (current page.south west) {Invited speakers are:\\[2mm]
{\color{white}First name}\\
His/her lecture\ldots\\
{\color{white}Second name}\\
Another lecture\ldots\\
{\color{white}Third name}\\
Another lecture\ldots\\
{\color{white}Fourth name}\\
Another lecture\ldots\\
{\color{white}Fifth name}\\
First tutorial\ldots\\
{\color{white}Sixth name}\\
Second tutorial\ldots
};
\node[align=right, xshift=-1cm, yshift=1cm, anchor=south east, font=\con, scale=1.4] at (current page.south east) {
{\bfseries\color{white}Organizer 1}\\
\bfseries and\\
{\bfseries\color{white}Organizer 2}\\
\bfseries invite you to participate in\\[5mm]
{\bfseries\color{white}\Large Name of the conference}\\[5mm]
{\color{white}\textit{Conference motto:}}\\
\bfseries Some text\\
{\color{white}\textit{Conference website:}}\\
\bfseries Some website\\
{\color{white}\textit{Contacts:}}\\
\bfseries Some email
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\mylogo myorange black 2 0 \par
%\mylogo mygray mygray 1 90
\end{document}
```

[image: skeleton of the poster]

Comment: Haha, +1.  Of course there's already a font of this nature....

Comment: +1 for the poster. What's the font used inside orange section?

Comment: @Ignasi It's Comfortaa, http://www.dafont.com/comfortaa.font

Comment: @Malipivo do you have TeXperience conference poster code. I want to make poster like TeXperience for my LaTeX Seminar.

Comment: @SKKhan Only a portion of it as logo itself was typeset in InDesign by my student who didn't know TeX. I tried to prepare a poster skeleton, please see update 2 in the post.