# How to define a new font family on Beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

How to define a new font family on Beamer?

I've tried this way, but I get `Undefined control sequence` :

```
\newfontfamily\fff{xxx.ttf}
```

Any good idea, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you compiling with Lua- oder XeLaTeX? Or normal pdfLaTeX? It would be best, if you upload a compilable document, just one frame, one word, and the packages needed here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @Djourma The command `\newfontfamily` is part of the package `fontenc` You are not able to use this with pdfLaTeX. If you are willing to change to LuaLaTeX, I can show you an answer. If not, you have to search for packages which load the font you like.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I've included that package using the `T1` option. But, in my case i'm note able to compile my presentation with another compiler. I can only use here pdfLaTex. In fact I'm just trying to reproduce [this font style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177085/want-to-make-the-poster). If you have another suggestion to get arround this situation, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi meant the `fontspec` package, not `fontenc`. And getting this font to work with pdflatex is possible but not easy.  Can you really not use xelatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and Djourma: Sorry, I tend to mix these up. On ttf in pdfLaTeX: http://superuser.com/a/161760

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, what's the difference between all of these compilers? Why hasn't LaTeX's users define a new standard compiler ?

Comment: Different people have different needs and so different compilers exist. If you now have the need to use a specific font which is difficult with pdflatex but easy with the new engines xelatex and lualatex as they can use system font out of the box then consider to switch.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\newcommand\palatino{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\palatino Title in Palatino}{Subtitle}
foo
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A list of the family names for `pdftex` is available here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/fontname/fontname.pdf (p. 30ff)

If you want to use a TrueType or OpenType font then use `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Then it is easier, for example:

```
\newfontfamily\DVS{Deja Vu Sans}
```

Comment: Isn't possible to use a local `ttf` file as a font style with pdfLaTeX ?

Comment: Yes, but that is not easy. See http://devnotcorp.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/use-truetype-font-with-pdflatex/